# Leaflet: maps are not updated

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I developed dynamic graphics with Leaflet.js in my project using my local machine. When applying some filters, the map must be updated. On the local machine it works perfectly. However, when uploading to my university's server, I ran into a problem: the maps are not being updated. I've tried using `map.remove` and `map.off`, but they're still the same. Looks like the map is still kept in some kind of cache. My application is being developed in PHP + Postgres + Apache. How can I solve?

My code:

```
function mapGenerator(zoom, coords, title, dataSource, yearCollection, typeTerritory, rangeLegend, user) {
    if (user) {
        mapUrl = "../assets/js/temp-geojson/" + user + "|geojson.js";
    } else {
        mapUrl = "../assets/js/temp-geojson/geojson.js";
    }

    if (map !== undefined && map !== null) {
        map.off();
        map.remove();
    }
    map = L.map('map').setView(coords, zoom);
    map.spin(true);

    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        minZoom: 2,
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: '&copy;  <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
        id: 'mapbox/light-v9',
        tileSize: 512,
        zoomOffset: -1
    }).addTo(map);


    // control that shows state info on hover
    var info = L.control();

    info.onAdd = function (map) {
        this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
        this.update();
        return this._div;
    };

    info.update = function (props) {
        this._div.innerHTML = '<h6><b>' + title + ' por ' + typeTerritory + '</b></h6>' + (props ?
            '<b>' + props.localizacao + '</b>: ' +
            '<br>' + props.valor.toLocaleString() + ' ha.'
            : 'Passe o mouse sobre a localização desejada');
    };

    info.addTo(map);

    // get color depending on population density value
    function getColor(d) {
        return d > rangeLegend[6] ? '#12500c' :
            d > rangeLegend[5] ? '#36640f' :
                d > rangeLegend[4] ? '#547915' :
                    d > rangeLegend[3] ? '#728f1f' :
                        d > rangeLegend[2] ? '#90a52d' :
                            d > rangeLegend[1] ? '#c8d029' :
                                d > rangeLegend[0] ? '#e5e738' :
                                    '#ffff5b';
    }

    function style(feature) {
        return {
            weight: 2,
            opacity: 1,
            color: 'white',
            dashArray: '3',
            fillOpacity: 0.7,
            fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.valor)
        };
    }

    function highlightFeature(e) {
        var layer = e.target;

        layer.setStyle({
            weight: 5,
            color: '#666',
            dashArray: '',
            fillOpacity: 0.7
        });

        if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera && !L.Browser.edge) {
            layer.bringToFront();
        }

        info.update(layer.feature.properties);
    }

    var geojson;

    function resetHighlight(e) {
        geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
        info.update();
    }

    function zoomToFeature(e) {
        map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
    }

    function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        layer.on({
            mouseover: highlightFeature,
            mouseout: resetHighlight,
            click: function () {
                layer.bindPopup('<b>' + feature.properties.localizacao + '</b>' +
                    '<br>' + feature.properties.valor.toLocaleString() + ' ha.').openPopup()
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Is your "update" reflected in the value of your `mapUrl` variable? If so, how is this variable used?

Comment: have you checked whether the file itself is being updated? I ran into a similar problem with my uni servers too which I was able to quick-fix using force clear cache option on browser. Otherwise I would have to wait 5-10 minutes to see the changes.

Comment: @ghybs Every time the user applies a filter, a new geojson is generated with the new data that is later saved in the `mapUrl` variable (I used to have a default geojson, which I removed for lack of use).

Comment: @Democrats I've tried cleaning cache, tried using another browser too, but the problem is probably with Apache. Although I made the installation on the virtual machine very similar to my local machine, I had to do an `auto_version()` function for the scripts to be updated after the modifications.